# The data is seen after sending in the form, what can it be?

Tags: node.js, angular

The data is seen after sending in the form, which may be I am using angular as frontend and nodejs as backend, I would greatly appreciate the support please, it should be noted that I am a beginner in angular

```html
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Acceso al Sistema
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form (submit)="login()" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.contrasenia" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              Ingresar
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class Usuarios {

  constructor(email=''){
    this.email = email
  }
  _id:string;
  nombre_completo: string;
  apellido_paterno:string;
  apellido_materno:string;
  roles:string;
  email:string;
  contrasenia:string;

}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? What you want to achieve? You're able to see information sent because you are inspecting what you are sending. It is in the body of the request, so, if you do not want an attacker to see it, you should use HTTPS. But I guess you (as sender) will be always able to see what you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

You can Encrypt the data and send to server and in the server side you can decrypt the data Please find the sample code below

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';




  decryptParams(result, password) {
    // console.log('to decrypt' + result);
    let decryptedString: any;
    const words = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(result);
    // console.log('to decrypt' + words);
    const textString = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(words);
    decryptedString = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textString, password);
    decryptedString = this.hex2a(decryptedString);
    return JSON.parse(decryptedString);
  }


  encryptParams(params, password) {
    let encryptedParams: any;
    encryptedParams = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(params), password);
    encryptedParams = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encryptedParams);
    encryptedParams = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedParams);
    // console.log('encry' + encryptedParams);
    return encryptedParams;
  }


 hex2a(hexx) {
    const hex = hexx.toString(); // force conversion
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));

    }
    return str;
  }
```

Comment: I have a user registration API on the server I am using nodejs that at the moment encrypts the password and compares it at login, do I also have to encrypt in the frontend?

Comment: Yes You should encrypt just before sending too server preferably in Intercepter. In the server side you can create a middle ware to decrypt al input params. The ame applicable to response from server encryp before send and decrypt in clien